# Incrementally add time to a date column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe which has a datetime64 time series in Yr-Month-Day format.I want to add hrs and minutes to the time series and also increment by 7 minutes for each observation until the next date occurs(starting from 9 AM in the morning).for example,

```
Date
2010-02-05
2010-02-05
2010-02-05
2010-02-12
2010-02-12
2010-02-12
```

I want the output as

```
Date
2010-02-05 09:07
2010-02-05 09:14
2010-02-05 09:21
2010-02-12 09:07
2010-02-12 09:14
2010-02-12 09:21
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `groupby` and `cumcount`, then do a little postprocessing to get the right units of time.

```
hrs = pd.Timedelta(hours=9)
min = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('Date').cumcount().add(1).mul(7), unit='m')
df['Date'] + hrs + min 

0   2010-02-05 09:07:00
1   2010-02-05 09:14:00
2   2010-02-05 09:21:00
3   2010-02-12 09:07:00
4   2010-02-12 09:14:00
5   2010-02-12 09:21:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```